# Dataweave 2.0 array filtering based on another arrays values

Tags: arrays, filter, dataweave, mulesoft

I'm attempting to try and match/filter the following lineId values in the unmatchedIds array to then filter the result set of exampleFile, by processorTransactionId. The result would be the removal of the last financialTransactionEntity, with the processorTransactionId = "000000062121029333".

In theory the sizes of both the unmatchedIds array and exampleFile array could be unbounded.

Any guidance/advice/examples would be much appreciated. I'm having difficult using the dataweave filter to achieve this at the moment.

```
{
  "unmatchedIds": [
    {
      "lineId": "000000062121029111"
    },
    {
      "lineId": "000000062121029222"
    }
  ]
}
```

exampleFile

```
[{
        "financialTransactionEntity": {
            "cardAcceptor": {
                "name": "Burger Inc.",
                "countryCode": "GBP"
            },
            "financialTransaction": {
                "debitOrCredit": "C",
                "amountInOriginalCurrency": {
                    "amount": "0000001000",
                    "exponent": "2"
                },
                "originalCurrencyCode": "826",
                "transactionDate": "2020-02-18"
            },
            "processorTransactionId": "000000062121029111"
        }
    },
    {
        "financialTransactionEntity": {
            "cardAcceptor": {
                "name": "McDonalds Inc.",
                "countryCode": "GBP"
            },
            "financialTransaction": {
                "debitOrCredit": "C",
                "amountInOriginalCurrency": {
                    "amount": "0000002000",
                    "exponent": "2"
                },
                "originalCurrencyCode": "826",
                "transactionDate": "2020-02-18"
            },
            "processorTransactionId": "000000062121029222"
        }
    },
    {
        "financialTransactionEntity": {
            "cardAcceptor": {
                "name": "McDonalds Inc.",
                "countryCode": "GBP"
            },
            "financialTransaction": {
                "debitOrCredit": "C",
                "amountInOriginalCurrency": {
                    "amount": "0000002000",
                    "exponent": "2"
                },
                "originalCurrencyCode": "826",
                "transactionDate": "2020-02-18"
            },
            "processorTransactionId": "000000062121029333"
        }
    }

]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of data selector with filter. See below

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java

import * from dw::core::Arrays

var unMatchedIds = {
  "unmatchedIds": [
    {
      "lineId": "000000062121029111"
    },
    {
      "lineId": "000000062121029222"
    }
  ]
}

var payload = [{
        "financialTransactionEntity": {
            "cardAcceptor": {
                "name": "Burger Inc.",
                "countryCode": "GBP"
            },
            "financialTransaction": {
                "debitOrCredit": "C",
                "amountInOriginalCurrency": {
                    "amount": "0000001000",
                    "exponent": "2"
                },
                "originalCurrencyCode": "826",
                "transactionDate": "2020-02-18"
            },
            "processorTransactionId": "000000062121029111"
        }
    },
    {
        "financialTransactionEntity": {
            "cardAcceptor": {
                "name": "McDonalds Inc.",
                "countryCode": "GBP"
            },
            "financialTransaction": {
                "debitOrCredit": "C",
                "amountInOriginalCurrency": {
                    "amount": "0000002000",
                    "exponent": "2"
                },
                "originalCurrencyCode": "826",
                "transactionDate": "2020-02-18"
            },
            "processorTransactionId": "000000062121029222"
        }
    },
    {
        "financialTransactionEntity": {
            "cardAcceptor": {
                "name": "McDonalds Inc.",
                "countryCode": "GBP"
            },
            "financialTransaction": {
                "debitOrCredit": "C",
                "amountInOriginalCurrency": {
                    "amount": "0000002000",
                    "exponent": "2"
                },
                "originalCurrencyCode": "826",
                "transactionDate": "2020-02-18"
            },
            "processorTransactionId": "000000062121029333"
        }
    }

]

---

using (unMatchedArray = unMatchedIds.unmatchedIds.*lineId)
payload[?(unMatchedArray contains $.financialTransactionEntity.processorTransactionId)]
```

unMatchedArray here is just a list of unmatched ids coming from your original object (unMatchedIds). Data selector will just include entry if financialTransactionEntity.processorTransactionId is in the unMatchedArray.

Comment: Why use "using" ?  Could you just define that as a variable or even inline it into the filter?

Comment: For this context there is no reason aside from making it clear on what it represents. As you mentioned you can declare it as a var or define it inline in the filter. On related note, I am just used to use "using" especially for nested payloads.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupBy` and `filter` functions to achieve the result. First, you can group `unMatchIds` by `lineId` and then you can apply a filter on your actual payload to eliminate all unmatched items.

```
output application/json
var unMatchIdsGrouped = var.unMatchIds.unmatchedIds groupBy $.lineId
---
payload filter ((item) -> unMatchIdsGrouped[ item.financialTransactionEntity.processorTransactionId] !=null)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest transforming the `unmatchedIds` object to an array of `id`'s, then filtering `exampleFile` objects based on whether or not the `processorTransactionId` is found in the compared array using `contains` full script:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java


var unMatchedIds = {
  "unmatchedIds": [
    {
      "lineId": "000000062121029111"
    },
    {
      "lineId": "000000062121029222"
    }
  ]
}

var exampleFile = [{
        "financialTransactionEntity": {
            "cardAcceptor": {
                "name": "Burger Inc.",
                "countryCode": "GBP"
            },
            "financialTransaction": {
                "debitOrCredit": "C",
                "amountInOriginalCurrency": {
                    "amount": "0000001000",
                    "exponent": "2"
                },
                "originalCurrencyCode": "826",
                "transactionDate": "2020-02-18"
            },
            "processorTransactionId": "000000062121029111"
        }
    },
    {
        "financialTransactionEntity": {
            "cardAcceptor": {
                "name": "McDonalds Inc.",
                "countryCode": "GBP"
            },
            "financialTransaction": {
                "debitOrCredit": "C",
                "amountInOriginalCurrency": {
                    "amount": "0000002000",
                    "exponent": "2"
                },
                "originalCurrencyCode": "826",
                "transactionDate": "2020-02-18"
            },
            "processorTransactionId": "000000062121029222"
        }
    },
    {
        "financialTransactionEntity": {
            "cardAcceptor": {
                "name": "McDonalds Inc.",
                "countryCode": "GBP"
            },
            "financialTransaction": {
                "debitOrCredit": "C",
                "amountInOriginalCurrency": {
                    "amount": "0000002000",
                    "exponent": "2"
                },
                "originalCurrencyCode": "826",
                "transactionDate": "2020-02-18"
            },
            "processorTransactionId": "000000062121029333"
        }
    }

]

---
exampleFile filter (unMatchedIds.unmatchedIds.lineId contains $.financialTransactionEntity.processorTransactionId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another answer ....Hope it helps

```
    %dw 2.2
output application/json
var inpUnmatchedIds = {
  "unmatchedIds": [
    {
      "lineId": "000000062121029111"
    },
    {
      "lineId": "000000062121029222"
    }
  ]
}
var exampleIds = [{
        "financialTransactionEntity": {
            "cardAcceptor": {
                "name": "Burger Inc.",
                "countryCode": "GBP"
            },
            "financialTransaction": {
                "debitOrCredit": "C",
                "amountInOriginalCurrency": {
                    "amount": "0000001000",
                    "exponent": "2"
                },
                "originalCurrencyCode": "826",
                "transactionDate": "2020-02-18"
            },
            "processorTransactionId": "000000062121029111"
        }
    },
    {
        "financialTransactionEntity": {
            "cardAcceptor": {
                "name": "McDonalds Inc.",
                "countryCode": "GBP"
            },
            "financialTransaction": {
                "debitOrCredit": "C",
                "amountInOriginalCurrency": {
                    "amount": "0000002000",
                    "exponent": "2"
                },
                "originalCurrencyCode": "826",
                "transactionDate": "2020-02-18"
            },
            "processorTransactionId": "000000062121029222"
        }
    },
    {
        "financialTransactionEntity": {
            "cardAcceptor": {
                "name": "McDonalds Inc.",
                "countryCode": "GBP"
            },
            "financialTransaction": {
                "debitOrCredit": "C",
                "amountInOriginalCurrency": {
                    "amount": "0000002000",
                    "exponent": "2"
                },
                "originalCurrencyCode": "826",
                "transactionDate": "2020-02-18"
            },
            "processorTransactionId": "000000062121029333"
        }
    }
]
---
exampleIds filter (value) -> ((((inpUnmatchedIds pluck $.lineId))[0]) contains (value.financialTransactionEntity.processorTransactionId))
```